# How to reorder columns and rows in kable or kableextra?

Tags: r, kable, kableextra

I'm trying to get a kable to display the rows and columns in an order other than the default one. For example, in the below example, the rows will be A, B, C. Is there a way to make them C, A, B in the kable instead?

Right now, I'm using the hacky method of putting letters in front of certain row names to force the default order to be different, but I don't want these letters in the final output because they look silly.

```
Product = c('A','B','A','A','C','B')
Month = c('Jan', 'Feb', 'Feb', 'Apr', 'Jan', 'Feb')
my_data = data.frame(Product, Month)
my_table = table(my_data)
kable(my_table) #This defaults to alphabetical order
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `my_table[c(3,1,2),]` ?

Comment: oh wow, it's actually that easy lol. whoops.

Comment: @Jason make that an answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you use factors instead of character values, you can set the ordering.

```
Product = factor(c('A','B','A','A','C','B'), levels = c('C', 'A', 'B'))
```